# opencv c++ can't open camera

Tags: c++, camera, opencv, python

In this code with c++ I tried to open camera but I got `can't open camera` and `GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()){
        cout << "can't open camera" << endl;
    }
}
```

but in python when I tried

```
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.read()
```

I got frame and camera opened successfully!!!
What should I do? what is wrong in c++?

Comment: Its a library issue not a C++ issue

Comment: make sure you have built opencv properly.

Comment: @solarflare which library?

Comment: @codekaizer yes , of course

Comment: does the camera works in another webcam app? that is basically an error that comes from Gstreamer which is used in the background. OpenCV can use this one FFMPEG and  some other ones... you can always try using another one and check the results